# Method to construct a finite state machine for a finite-size language L

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

I need to define a method to construct a finite automata for a finite language L (part of my proof for something else).
My idea:

1. Create $|L|$ accepting states.
2. For each input string $s$ from $L$, create appropriate transitions from a starting state to unique accepting state of s.

I don't know how to formally describe this, or if this idea is even good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the list of all prefixes of words in $L$. Create a DFA with a state $q_s$ for each $s \in S$, and an additional sink state $q_\bot$. The starting state is $q_\epsilon$, and a state is accepting if it corresponds to a word in $L$. When at a non-sink state $q_s$, upon reading $\sigma$, move to $q_{s\sigma}$ if $s\sigma \in S$, and to $q_\bot$ otherwise. When at $q_\bot$, always stay there.

To show that this works, prove inductively that when reading a word $w$, if $w \in S$ then the DFA is at state $q_w$, and otherwise it's at state $q_\bot$.

Comment: Thank you! For proving this, would i induct on length of w ?

Comment: Right, induction is on the length of the word.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful :)

Comment: One thing I'd add, S is a set of all $proper$ prefixes of words in L since prefix that's the word itself should be omitted in this case.

Comment: No, $S$ ought to contain *all* prefixes.

Comment: Ok I think I made up a new method out of a mis-understanding. I don't have a sink state. I have a last state that input "goes to" after reading the last letter. That last state is the only accepting state and is the last state for all strings that are in L. All other non-accepting states are actually all proper substrings of words in L. Note: If L accepts emptystring then q(emptystring) also becomes an accepting state.

Comment: You're right that the construction can be optimized. In some cases it could be optimized even further.